# Rails create join table how to validate uniqueness of pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've created a join table with

```
rails generate migration CreateJoinTableFoosBars foos bars
```

and it has indeed created a working joining table, however I can't see the model for it and thus I can't add the

```
validates_uniqueness_of :foo_id, scope: :bar_id
```

How can I do it in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you create a model manually for it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a unique index that includes both columns. That will prevent you from inserting a record that contains a duplicate foo_id/bar_id pair.

```
add_index :foo_bars, [:foo_id, :bar_id], unique: true
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question, but I'm new to rails, I have to create a migration and add this line in it, correct?

Comment: Yes, after you created the join table

Answer (score -3):

generating a migration does not generate a model as well. If you use the model generator then it will also produce a migration file and the model file:

```
rails generate model foo_bar foo_id:integer bar_id:integer
```